# How to calculate the correlation coefficient of two independent random walks to demonstrate spurious regression?

Tags: random-walk, regression-analysis

I heard of non-stationary time series could result in spurious regression, so I want to know, as sample size goes to infinity, how to calculate the correlation coefficient of two descrete independent random walks, each step of which follows an I.I.D standard normal distribution.

Is it the correct way to demonstrate spurious regression?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the covariance of 2 independent random variables?

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's zero. But how to demonstrate the point of spurious regression? Because this seems to be a standard example to show that it's not correct to regress on a non-stationary time series.

Comment: No idea there @Epicurus XD Try stats SE